# How to access private field via BeanInfo<I> in java

Tags: java, reflection, field, private, beaninfo

I know how to access private fields via Class.forName() and Field[].
Now I am trying samething via BeanInfo Interface.

What I did is below.

1. get Class instance via Class.forName()
2. BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(Class) - Here, I can see 'org.owls.anno.vo.Target'.
3. get elements via for syntax.

   for(PropertyDescriptor pd : info.getPropertyDescriptors()){ 
   log.info(pd.getName());
   log.info(pd.getDisplayName());
   log.info(pd.getPropertyType());
   }
4. I expected list of Field names(msg, open_msg), but it prints 'class.java.lang.Class'.

The Target Class is here

```
package org.owls.anno.vo;

import org.owls.anno.SimpleAnnotation;

@SimpleAnnotation("Add missing attributes")
public class Target {
    private String msg;
    public String open_msg;

    public Target(String msg) {
        super();
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Target [msg=" + msg + "]";
    }
};
```

Thanks for Answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is not a bean: there is no accessor (getter and/or setter)...except `getClass()`!

Comment: So you mean if my Class is not a bean, then I can not get information of class via BeanInfo interface?

Comment: @JuneyoungOh Well, as far as I understand, you need getters (and setters). It is not based on private instance variables, which is quite logic, I think : you access them by the accessors, never directly.